# Function overloading getting ambiguous

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, overloading, overload-resolution

When overloading functions:

```
void add(int a)
{
    a=7;
    cout<<"int";
}
void add(double a)
{
    a=8.4;
    cout<<"double";
}
void add(int *b)
{
    *b=4;
    cout<<"pointer";
}
int main()
{
    char i='a';   //char
    add(i);
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT: `int`

This worked fine inspite of no function with data type char as parameter.

But when compiled below code:

```
void add(char a)
{
    a='a';
    cout<<"int";
}
void add(double a)
{
    a=8.4;
    cout<<"double";
}
void add(int *b)
{
    *b=4;
    cout<<"pointer";
}
int main()
{
    int i=4;  //int
    add(i);
    return 0;
}
```

Gave error(compiler gcc):

> cpp|21|error: call of overloaded 'add(int&)' is ambiguous

What is the logic behind this? And how to track the control passing or output of such codes?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution

Comment: What did you expect?

Comment: @n.m. i expected same error for above code....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This example boils down to the difference between Integer Promotion and Integer Conversion. A promotion is, in short:

> A prvalue of an integer type other than bool, char16_t, char32_t, or wchar_t whose integer conversion
>   rank (4.13) is less than the rank of int can be converted to a prvalue of type int if int can represent all
>   the values of the source type; otherwise, the source prvalue can be converted to a prvalue of type unsigned int. [...] These conversions are called integral promotions.

whereas an integer conversion is more general:

> A prvalue of an integer type can be converted to a prvalue of another integer type. [...] The conversions allowed as integral promotions are excluded from the set of integral conversions.

An integral promotion is a *better* conversion than an integral conversion for the purposes of overload resolution.

---

In the first example, we have:

```
add(int );    // (1)
add(double ); // (2)
add(int* );   // (3)
```

and are calling with a `char`. Only the first two are viable, both involve a conversion. (1) involves an Integer Promotion, which has rank Promotion. (2) involves a Floating-Integral Conversion, which has rank Conversion. Promotion is a higher rank than Conversion, so (1) is unambiguously preferred. [image]

Now, in the second example, we have:

```
add(char );   // (1)
add(double ); // (2)
add(int* );   // (3)
```

and are calling with an `int`. Once again, only the first two are viable, and both involve a conversion. (1) this time involves an Integral Conversion (since`char` has lower rank than `int`) and (2) still involves a Floating-integral conversion, both of which have the same rank: Conversion. As we have two conversions of the same rank, there is no "best" conversion, so there is no best viable candidate. Thus, we have an ambiguous resolution.

Comment: Thanx for your answer also can you provide any links to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Reason is when there is no exact type match, compiler looks for the closest match. 
Thats why when it was - `char i='a';` the closest match was `void add(int a)`

but when it is `int i=4;  //int` there are 2 match now. so that is why it is ambiguous.

Comment: add(int *b) and add(char a) both of them are receiving a int variable

Comment: I dont think so ,as removing function with `double` parameter for below code it ran successfully.

Comment: sorry my mistake. it would be add(int *b) and add(double a) who are competing.

Answer (score 1):

A `char` fits into an `int` without overflowing or losing precision, which explains the first code.

But an `int` doesn't fit into a `char` (overflow), `double` (lack of precision), or `int*` (incompatible type).

Comment: It is 'ambiguous' so isn't it over-fitting scenerio instead of "under-fitting" ?

Comment: @zenith when i removed char parameter function it gave output `double` for below code.....so `int` fits into `double`.

Comment: @zenith and same for `char` when i removed double it gave output `int` (under parameter char)so int also fits into `char i think`