# Passing 2D array as an argument to a function which takes 1D array

Tags: c++

Might sound like a stupid question:

Is it possible to pass 2D array as an argument to a function which takes 1D array

For example:

I have an array `players[4][5]` and also a function `bestCard()`, the header for that function looks something like this `void bestCard(int arr[5])` <- this `5` is referring to the second dimension of array `players`

I want to pass `players[4][...]` in the function `bestCard()` in a way that the only last dimension is considered to be as an array i.e `players[5]`

Not sure if my question is comprehensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a beginner at C++, but as far as I know, it would *not* be possible to pass a 2-d array to your function `bestCard()`, assuming that you have not  [overloaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33504353/function-overloading-getting-ambiguous) your `bestCard()` function to take different types of parameters.

Based on the information you have given to me in your question, I am guessing that there are 4 players, and each holds a hand of 5 cards.

If you want to pass `bestCard()` a single player's hand, you will have to write something like this:

```
bestCard(players[0]) // Determine the bestCard for the first player.
bestCard(players[1]) // Determine the bestCard for the second player.
...
bestCard(players[3]) // Determine the bestCard for the fourth player.
```

Even though `players` is in fact a 2-d array, each of the `players[i]` (for `0 < i < 4`) evaluate to 1-dimensional arrays. Thus, `bestCard()` ought to be able to accept them as an argument.

Comment: That's helpful! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A 2D array is an array of 1D arrays.

In your case, that means `player[i]` is an array of five elements, for `i` between `0` and `3`.   So passing `player[i]` to your function will pass an array of 5 elements (or more strictly, a pointer to the first element of an array of 5 elements).